# PowerShell Import-Module ActiveDirectory Takes 15+ Seconds to Load

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-4.0, import-module

I am using [ScriptRunner](https://scriptrunner.com) to run a script to Get-ADUser data. In the beginning of the script, I am running Import-Module ActiveDirectory. When run as NT Authority\System using PSExec on the ScriptRunner server (same as where ScriptRunner runs), it imports the module in .04 seconds, however when run via ScriptRunners process, it takes 16-18 seconds. The server does not have access to the internet or a proxy file leveraged. I have tried the ADSI route with the same issue. They suggested that it is an [OCSP](https://kb.scriptrunner.com/scripts/ocsp-requests) issue, but we do have an internal OCSP Responder, I just don't know how to point an Import-Module command for ActiveDirectory to use it. Any help/assistance would be greatly appreciated!

I have attempted to import other modules and they do not have this issue of adding considerable time to the script as ActiveDirectory does.

Comment: Is it not in your local module directory for powershell?

Comment: It is. When the ScriptRunner service starts, it loads the modules from the different module paths defined